# how to grab alt text to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

what is the simplest way to grab the alt text to a function in JavaScript?
tried .alt already.
This is my current function:

I have tried .alt all day

```js
function previewPic3(){ 
document.getElementById('image').style = "background: #fff url('URL')"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do indeed use the `.alt` property of the DOM object, but you may not have been successfully querying the DOM for the image in the first place.

```js
function previewPic3(){ 
  console.log(document.querySelector('img').alt);
}

previewPic3();
```

```html
<img src="https://example.com" alt="Hello!">
```